# Xcode uses different Text in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, string, xcode, interface-builder

This is weird.

So I have a UINavigationItem, where I changed the title from Books to whathaveiread in the Interface Builder.

When I build the app, it still displays Books.

When I delete whathaveiread out of the text area (and leave the field empty) the changes are applied in the simulator.

When I stop the simulator and write whathaveiread into the title field again, it uses the title Books again.

This behaviour isn't only with UINavigationItem, but with every string in the Interface Builder.

I've tried on different simulators, and a real device.

When I restarted Xcode, the affected Views were Suddenly completely invisible, only the different items in the view outlined with a blue border. (After it took unusually long to load the file)

After deleting DerivedData it still doesn't work.

Here is a video to explain it better:
https://youtu.be/YiYRdbwMY8Q

Comment: Super weird. How are you dismissing editing? I hit return I think before leaving the field. It does not make sense that how your doing it should not work but try hitting return before clicking away. If that works I would file a radar. Super weird

Comment: What is a radar? I was somehow to lazy to press enter i think, usually I do.

Comment: did pressing enter fix the issue? Radar is a bug report to Apple and how to reproduce.